# Matching tags not between [a] and [/a] tags

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have content like this:

```
[a]
[b]
[a]
[c]
[/a]
[c]
[a]
[b]
[c]
[/a]    
[/a]
[b]
[b]
[b]
[c]
```

I want to get the `[b]` or `[c]` tags that are not between `[a]` and `[/a]` tags.
My content has nested `[a][/a]` tags but `preg_match` should not select `[b]` or `[c]` nested there.

How can I do this?

Comment: are you talking about not taking [b] or [c] when are between [a] and [/a] tags at any level or just when [a] tag is immediate parent.

Comment: Yes I am talking about not taking b or c tags when they are between a tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: 
`(?&a)|(\[[bc]\])|(*F)(?:(?'a'\[a\](?&nest)\[/a\])|(?'nest'((?&a)|\[[bc]\]|\s)*))`

(Ensure you're using the `s`ingle-line modifier)

I've rewritten it as a context-free grammar.

### Explanation

- <strike>It's magic</strike>
- `(?&a)|(\[[bc]\])` Find things matching the pattern "a", but only capture `[b]`s or `[c]`s outside of the "a" patterns.
- `(*F)(?:(?'a'\[a\](?&nest)\[/a\])|(?'nest'((?&a)|\[[bc]\]|\s)*))`

  - This is a hackish way to declare subpatterns to use in the match, without the declarations actually being a part of the match.
- `(?'a'\[a\](?&nest)\[/a\])` Pattern "a" is `[a][/a]` and can have the "nest" pattern within it.
- `(?'nest'((?&a)|\[[bc]\]|\s)*)` The "nest" pattern is made of either another pattern "a", or a space, or `[b]` or `[c]`.

Comment: This pattern matching 4 b or c element like this ;http://prntscr.com/arzowl Thats okey working properly. But when [a][/a] tags between b or c tags it can not selecting tags. For example ; http://prntscr.com/arzpgg or http://prntscr.com/arzpbn

Comment: Try it now, I added a lazy `?`

Comment: @redfox9999 Assuming that you want to get the `[b] [c]`s that are inlined between `[a][/a]`s, here you are. IDK what was wrong with it the first time, anyway.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/as01w4. same problem. It's can not selecting [b] tags before [a][b][/a]

Comment: When [a][/a] tags before b or c tags its working https://regex101.com/r/uW8rZ8/1 , but when after not working https://regex101.com/r/jW3pG3/1

Comment: @redfox9999 I created an entire parser and updated my answer. I hope you're happy.